# Add a Configurable Variable in a @Builder Class

Tags: spring, lombok

I have a @Builder class and one of the variables used in that class needs to be configurable. I've tried

```
@Value("${string.propertiesFile}")  
private String stringValue;
```

where I'm inserting the a value defined in application.properties file into my `stringValue` variable. However, `stringValue` is always null. 
How can I add a inject a literal value into my @Builder Class?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand for the `@Value` annotation to work, spring needs to be in control of the bean creation process so that it can inject the value . `@Value` can be used for injecting values into fields in Spring-managed beans and it can be applied at the field or constructor/method parameter level. When using the lombok `@Builder` annotation you are essentially implementing the builder pattern. So spring is not in control of the bean creation hence you cannot inject the value directly into your class .

Instead what you could do is have the value injected using `@Value` in another **spring-managed class** from where you are using this builder and probably pass in the value to the builder like :

```
@Service
public SomeServiceClassImpl {

@Value("${string.propertiesFile}")  
private String stringValue;

 public void someMethod() {

   BuilderPatternClass testBuilderPatternClass =  BuilderPatternClass.builder()
     .name(stringValue)
     .id(1)
     .build();
  }

}
```